# Rest controller not being called in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Rest controller for my Restful calls. I'm having Spring 4.3.x version of JAR's. When I run the project itself, the index.jsp is not getting called. I've not configured anything in xml because I'm using annotation method. Here are my files.

P.S : I'm not using Maven, its a dynamic web project and all Spring JAR's (Webmvc, web, core, context, beans) are added to build path.

I've followed http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-4-mvc-rest-example-json/

### AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.ifg.spring")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

### AppInitializer

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

### CustomerDAO

```
public class CustomerDAO {

// Dummy database. Initialize with some dummy values.
private static List<Customer> customers;
{
    customers = new ArrayList();
    // Add customers here
}


public List list() {
    return customers;
}


}
```

### CustomerRestController

```
@RestController
public class CustomerRestController {


@Autowired
private CustomerDAO customerDAO;


@GetMapping("/customers")
public List getCustomers() {
    return customerDAO.list();
}

}
```

### Web.xml

```
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>IFG</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Why its not able to hit the URL http://localhost:8080/IFG/customers? There should be the issue with AppInitializer file.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any error on startup?

Comment: What http status are you getting?

Comment: I think you need to annotate your DAO with @Bean

Comment: You seem to be missing some annotations. Without annotations, `CustomerDAO` is not managed by Spring. More importantly, without annotations, `AppInitializer` will not be loaded by the Servlet container, which means that Spring is not loaded at all.

Comment: @MehrajMalik the problem is with AppInitializer file. Not able to understand whats the issue in it

Comment: @Andreas, Do you know whats the issue with AppInitializer

Comment: at server startup are u getting any errors?

Comment: also the code which u added in question is incomplete, pls put entire class from package statement, if your package is different spring will not recognize the components

Comment: No errors. When I comment the AppInitializer file, at least the index.jsp is opening. If I uncomment, its throwing 404 for index.jsp too. There is some problem with AppInitializer file itself. Can you please follow that tutorial with dynamic web project

Comment: I just copied those packages into my code

Comment: @NarendraJaggi, I've added the tutorial link in the question. Please find it.

Comment: Just came to know that its failing due to javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `IFG` in a request mapping. The current link according to your mapping should be `http://localhost:8080/customers`. Add the @RequestMapping annotation specifying the path.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/IFG")
public class CustomerRestController
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you should add:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/IFG")
```

and check the number of port: `8080` (it could be `9080` or whatever)

Comment: @Aliy Check the number of port and maybe start your application server :)

Comment: Its not working due to AppInitializer file. If I comment, the index page is opening.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/IFG")
public class CustomerRestController {


@Autowired
private CustomerDAO customerDAO;


@GetMapping("/customers")
public List getCustomers() {
    return customerDAO.list();
}

}
```

Now hit the url like below :

> localhost:port/IFG/customers

Comment: @No dear, still its same. I dont understand whats the problem in AppInitializer file

Answer (score 0):

After http://localhost:8080 you have to give your app name prior calling the controller. Lets say your app name is `myApp`, so the url should be:

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/customers`

provided you use the controller in your question, if you have added to your controller `@RequestMapping("/IFG")` as per other answers suggested then you have to change the url to:

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/IFG/customers`

**EDIT**

I see in your `AppInitializer` class you are returning null from `getServletConfigClasses()`. I believe that the `AppConfig.class` should be returned there.

```
@Override
protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}
```

Comment: At least the welcome index page should open.. This itself is not opening due to AppInitializer

Comment: I just found that its due to javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class

Answer (score 0):

Just try access `http://localhost:8080/customers` (without /IFG),  just copied that project locally, on my tomcat, and it works, without running `mvn tomcat7:run`.

Your setup in web.xml `<display-name>IFG</display-name>` is not the application context path by which to access.

From the docs:

> display-name
>
> The optional display-name element specifies the Web
> application display name, a short name that can be displayed by GUI
> tools.

Comment: Did you try in dynamic web project way? I didnt use Maven. I'm getting this error javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class

Answer (score 0):

Just checked that it was due to javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class. This I've fixed by adding commons-logging-1.2.jar, spring-aop, spring-expression jars. Atleast I'm able to point to the right method.